# How can I scrape Google?

Tags: web-scraping

How do I get HTML inside google.com?

Let's say I go to Google and type "Humpty Dumpty" and I get the search results and the URL changes to something like:

https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&q=humpty+dumpty&oq=humtp&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i10l10.7599.8190.0.9757.5.5.0.0.0.0.373.732.3j1j0j1.5.0....0...1c.1.30.serp..2.3.187.2B69R71ux4U

But when I try to `HttpWebRequest` to download this webpage I don't get any search result HTML inside of it. I think this is because Google makes request for results after the page is loaded?

Is there any way I can get the HTML?

P.S: I know scraping from Google is against their TOS. I am trying to learn of how to scrape such websites.

Comment: why negative votes? Is this off topic?

Comment: Use F12 developer tools to understand how interactive web pages work.

Comment: @Ben: Do you know how they work? Why not share with me then?

Comment: Try using google (without scraping) to find out how the developer tools work....

Comment: @Jack, they can work in many different ways. If you use the network tab on F12 developer tools you can see how **this** one works. And don't be rude to the people you want to help you.

Comment: Try turning off JavaScript in your browser, and then use Google again - it will behave in a much simpler way. It will fall back to a standard GET form, which can be scraped in a much more trivial way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the below code, I'm seeing the correct HTML coming back (something coming back about nursery rhymes)

The below code uses WebClient to retrieve the correct HTML

```
WebClient wbclient = new WebClient();
string html = wbclient.DownloadString("https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&q=humpty+dumpty&oq=humtp&gs_l=serp.3.0.0i10l10.7599.8190.0.9757.5.5.0.0.0.0.373.732.3j1j0j1.5.0....0...1c.1.30.serp..2.3.187.2B69R71ux4U");
```

Comment: Thanks. Interesting. The other day I was seeing some JSON file and not the actual HTML.

Comment: i've just tried this again (using HttpWebRequest) and the same html comes back. I did think initially that not setting any request headers would mean google would know that it was not a browser requesting data, however that does not seem to bother it.
What code do you have that is not working? could you update the question with it?